# Pass client side js variable to handlebars helper

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js, helper

I'm trying to build a list of data on the client side by iterating over server side data. Whenever I input the parameter into the helper function call I think handlebars is trying to evaluate the function before the client code runs. The helper then fails because it doesn't receive an index.

```
for(i = 0; i< 10;i++){
  document.write('<img src="{{get_pic '+i+'}}">');
}
```

Comment: Your `for` loop has some interesting syntax...

Comment: Should be fixed now

Comment: What is the error? Where is the helper?